# Problem building a flutter app - Errors with Android DEX

Tags: flutter, build, dex

When building our flutter-app I get the following error. Its a flutter only project. We are using Intellij Idea Ultimate to build it.

How can I fix the following errors?

Here is the build-output:

```
Executing pre-compile tasks...
Loading Ant Configuration...
Running Ant Tasks...
Running 'before' tasks
Checking sources
Generating R.java and Manifest.java files [apps.community]
Parsing java... [apps.community]
Writing classes... [apps.community]
Checking dependencies... [apps.community]
Dependency analysis found 0 affected files
Updating dependency information... [apps.community]
Adding @NotNull assertions... [apps.community]
Adding pattern assertions... [apps.community]
Android Resource Caching: Caching resources [apps.community]
Android Resource Caching: [apps.community] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: C:\Development\SOME_PATH...
Android Resource Caching: [apps.community] To destination dir: C:\Users\SOME_PATH...
Packaging resources [apps.community]
Executing DEX [apps.dev]
Android Dex: [apps.dev] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/gradle/cli/AbstractCommandLineConverter;
...
Android Dex: [apps.dev] Uncaught translation error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Lorg/gradle/cli/CommandLineParser$AfterOptions;
Android Dex: [apps.dev] Unable to execute DX
Android Dex: [apps.dev] java.lang.RuntimeException: Translation has been interrupted
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:614)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:310)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runDx(Main.java:288)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:264)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.runDex(AndroidDxRunner.java:201)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at org.jetbrains.android.compiler.tools.AndroidDxRunner.main(AndroidDxRunner.java:349)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: Too many errors
Android Dex: [apps.dev] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processAllFiles(Main.java:606)
Android Dex: [apps.dev] ... 9 more
javac 11.0.8 was used to compile java sources
Finished, saving caches...
Executing post-compile tasks...
Loading Ant Configuration...
Running Ant Tasks...
Synchronizing output directories...
``
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was connected with gradle as changes there and updates of the gradle plugin solved the problem.